# The answer is not really an answer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers

This [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/956/cannot-install-open-atrium/963#963), written by who asked the question, is not really an answer, but it should be an edit of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special case in the flag dialog for that:

> **Not an answer**
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it
>   does not answer the question. It
>   should possibly be an edit, a comment,
>   another question, or deleted
>   altogether

Just flag this kind of answers and a moderator can delete them, edit the question or convert them into a comment. But you need to flag these kinds of posts, moderators depend on the community to bring such issues to their attention.

There are also no pro-tem moderators announced yet, although that should happen pretty soon. So the only moderators for now are SE employees that have to divide their attention between multiple sites.

Leaving a comment to educate people is also a possibility.

Comment: Flags for modearator attention age away after 2−4 days; as we don't have pro-tempore moderators, I have created a post here too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical rookie mistake, all you can really do, is try to educate people, or downvote these types of *answers*. It happens on SO as well.

Comment: And, especially with "rookie mistakes," try and leave a thoughtful, explanatory comment to *educate* users who come after.